# Should I flag questions where the code posted works fine?

Tags: discussion, support

So today I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29878538/2987066) which asks a

> ListView.Click += ListView_Click no working

The code that has been posted works fine and OP also acknoledges that his code works fine in a follow up comment.

I was wondering whether I should flag the question as it's not really a question and doesn't add anything to the site; and if so what reason should I flag the question under?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a closing/flagging reason exactly for this sort of question:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

[image]

To find it in the flagging menu:

```
-> Flag
    -> Should be closed...
        -> Off topic because...
            -> Reason...
```

There are other common close reasons in the same section.  There's also some common close reasons on the same screen as "Off topic because..." such as "Unclear what you're asking" and "Too Broad".

Comment: I cannot flag questions to be closed because of my reputation. Sadly I don't think a flag exists with this reason though

Comment: Flag -> Should be closed -> Off topic because -> [this reason]

Comment: Wow thats pretty hidden. I feel there should be something to identify flags that break down into more reasons. Thanks

Comment: @user1 there is! Options which break down into submenus usually end with an ellipsis, `...`. For example "Should be closed..." or "Is a duplicate...". _Final_ options, such as "Spam" or "Needs a moderator intervention" don't have the `...`

Comment: @AJPerez Oh yea well spotted! that wasn't initially clear to me

Answer (score 1):

You can suggest OP to delete the question as it won't contribute anything to site or future user.

Comment: Or flag it as explained in nhgriff's answer, and it will be autodeleted by the system after seven days.